# How to choose a solution of a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

```
delta = -(1/r D[#, r] + D[#, {r, 2}] - # l^2/r^2) &;
DSolve[delta[
    g[r]] + (B l + B^2 r^2/4) g[r] == en g[
    r], g[r], r]
```

The solution proposed by Mathematica is okay yet one can find an alternative, less complex representation with [Whittaker functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WhittakerFunction.html). Is it possible to force Mathematica to use a certain type of function as a solution of a differential equation? We do not impose any boundary conditions.

In this specific problem one can always use a transformation rule for the confluent hypergeometric function, for instance

```
rule = HypergeometricU[a_, b_, z_] -> 
  E^(z/2) z^(-b/2) WhittakerW[b/2 - a, (b - 1)/2, z];
```

but this is just a workaround. Perhaps there is a more elegant way.

**Edit**

For instance, consider the harmonic oscillator equation

```
DSolve[-y''[x] == y[x], y[x], x]
{{y[x] -> C[1] Cos[x] + C[2] Sin[x]}}
```

Is it possible to force a solution with exponential functions? Of course, the replacement rule can be used but perhaps there is a deeper solution.

```
{{y[x] -> C[1] Exp[I x] + C[2] Exp[-I x]}}
```

It would be great if Mathematica could provide a list of exemplary solutions (but this is just wishful thinking:-).

Comment: Side comment: even `FullSimplify[DSolve[…], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. rule &}]` doesn't return solution with WhittakkerW. (Though I personally don't have any experience with this option.)

Comment: Righ, this doesn't work (sorry, I have no time to check why, gotta go in a sec). If you tried applying my rule to the  output of DSolve, then there should be a substitution.

Comment: @GregoryRut This might be an  interesting question, however you should explain more clearly what you expect to get. This `rule` works fine and it might be easily demeonstrated that's true, however the system finds a combination of `LaguerreL` and `WhittakerW` more complicated than combnations of hypergeometric functions with `Pochhammer`.

Comment: @GregoryRut You still haven't posed precisely your question. Appropriate initial condition in principle can provide an adequate function (solution). However if you don't want specify initial conditions you could evaluate e.g. `Collect[TrigToExp[C[1] Cos[x] + C[2] Sin[x]], E^(I x)]`, but in general it depends on case by case basis.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to specify preferred functions for the output of `DSolve`. Your "workaround" of explicitly applying the desired transformation rule is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if this would be what you want, but using [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) well as [`TransformationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunction.html)can get you somewhere.

```
cf[expr_] := 100 Count[expr, _HypergeometricU, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[expr]
tf[expr_] := expr /. HypergeometricU[a_, b_, z_] :>
              E^(z/2) z^(-b/2) WhittakerW[b/2 - a, (b - 1)/2, z]

FullSimplify[sol, ComplexityFunction -> cf, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]

(* (2^(l/2) (r^2)^((
 1 + l)/2) (Sqrt[2] E^((B r^2)/4)
     C[2] LaguerreL[-((B + en)/(2 B)), l, -((B r^2)/2)] + 
   2^((2 + l)/2) (-B r^2)^(1/2 (-1 - l))
     C[1] WhittakerW[1/2 (-(en/B) + l), l/2, -((B r^2)/2)]))/r *)
```

You need to make `HypergeometricU[a,b,z]` more "complex" than `E^(z/2) z^(-b/2) WhittakerW[b/2 - a, (b - 1)/2, z]` in order to force FullSimplify to consider "moving" in that direction.